# Updating MS SQL table with the xml data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have my data in XML format which i want to UPDATE into my existing table.
The data in xml format is as follows:

```
var xmldata = "<ansid>0</ansid><quesid>1</quesid><ansid>1</ansid><quesid>2</quesid><ansid>1</ansid><quesid>3</quesid>"
```

I wanted to update the same into existing table

```
quesid | ansid
_____________
1      |0 
2      |0
3      |0
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: You need to shred the data and do an UPDATE JOIN

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this:

```
    DECLARE @xml xml = '<ansid>0</ansid>
                        <quesid>1</quesid>
                        <ansid>1</ansid>
                        <quesid>2</quesid>
                        <ansid>1</ansid>
                        <quesid>3</quesid>'

    ;
    WITH ans as
    (
    SELECT t.x.value ('.', 'nvarchar(100)') ansid , ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) Seq
    FROM @xml.nodes ('ansid') t(x)
    ), ques as 

    (
    SELECT t.x.value ('.', 'nvarchar(100)') quesid , ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) Seq
    FROM @xml.nodes ('quesid') t(x)
    )
    SELECT ques.quesid, ans.ansid 
    FROM ans
    JOIN ques
    ON ques.Seq = ANS.Seq
```

Will return:

```
quesid  ansid
     1      0
     2      1
     3      1
```